# JavaScript not working in Cordova Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am developing an hybrid App, created html page and css ,in html i have included JavaScript but simple alert message is also not working ,and in javascript (index.js) have created validate function please help me.

```js
var attempt = 3; // Variable to count number of attempts.
// Below function Executes on click of login button.
function validate() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if (username == "abcdef" && password == "abc#123") {
        alert("Login successfully");
        window.location = "success.html"; // Redirecting to other page.
        return false;
    }
    else {
        attempt--;// Decrementing by one.
        alert("You have left " + attempt + " attempt;");
        // Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
        if (attempt == 0) {
            document.getElementById("username").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
/* Below line is used for online Google font */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
body{
    background :#f2ca78;
}
h2{
/*/background-color: #FEFFED;*/
padding: 30px 35px;
margin: -10px -50px;
text-align:center;
border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
hr{
margin: 10px -50px;
border: 0;
border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
margin-bottom: 40px;
}
/*div.container{
width: 900px;
height: 610px;
margin:35px auto;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}*/

div.main{
background-color: #f8f2f2;
width: 230px;
padding: 10px 50px 25px;
border: 2px solid gray;
border-radius: 10px;
font-family: raleway;
float:left;
margin-top:50px;
}
input[type=text],input[type=password]{
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
padding: 5px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
margin-top: 5px;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
color: #4f4f4f;
font-size: 16px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
label{
color: #464646;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
}
center{
font-size:32px;
}
.note{
color:red;
}
.valid{
color:green;
}
.back{
text-decoration: none;
border: 1px solid rgb(0, 143, 255);
background-color: rgb(0, 214, 255);
padding: 3px 20px;
border-radius: 2px;
color: black;
}
input[type=button]{
font-size: 16px;
background: linear-gradient(#ffbc00 5%, #ffdd7f 100%);
border: 1px solid #e5a900;
color: #4E4D4B;
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 10px 0;
outline:none;
}
input[type=button]:hover{
background: linear-gradient(#ffdd7f 5%, #ffbc00 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <!--
        Customize the content security policy in the meta tag below as needed. Add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src to enable inline JavaScript.
        For details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617521
    -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
       <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <script typ="test/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
        <title>BlankCordovaApp1</title>

</head>
    <body bgcolor="pink">
        <h1 style="color:black;text-align:center"> HEALTH APP</h1>
        <!--<div class="container">-->
        <div class="main">
            <h2>Welcome</h2>
            <form id="form_id" method="post" name="myform">
                <label>User Name :</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
                <label>Password :</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
                <button type="button" value="Login" id="submit" onclick="validate()" />
            </form>
            <span><b class="note">Note : </b>For this demo use following username and password. <br /><b class="valid">User Name : abcdef<br />Password : abc#123</b></span>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your button tag is not well-formed, should be something like:

```<button type="button" id="submit" onclick="validate()" >Login</button>```

Comment: this also i have tried , its not working

Comment: onclick validate function ,, or any simple javascrpit also not working in cordova

Answer (score 0):

You can't run javascript in html files in Cordova. You need to add an event listener in your index.js file :

```
 document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', validate);
```

Then write your **function validate()** in this same file.